# Send the reminder email as per reminder date in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Given**
Column G is having the expected return date(i.e. reminder date).
Column J is having email address stored
Column L is having return status

**Need**
Need to send the reminder email(email address Col J) on the reminder date(COl G) if the Column L (Return_Status) is blank.

I already have a code written, can't figure out the exact issue why it is not working.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails() {
var today = new Date().toLocaleDateString();  // Today's date, without time

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = 999;   // Number of rows to process
// Fetch the range of cells A2:B999
//var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 999)
//var dataRange= sheet.getRange("Form Responses 1!A1:L");
var dataRange= sheet.getRange(startRow,numRows)
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = "dummy@gmail.com";
var subject = "RC Reminder # "+row[3];  
var message = "Reminder for "+row[4]+" RC of vehicle"+row[3]+" handed over to "+row[5]+"     against "+row[2]+" on "+row[0];  
var emailSent = row[10];  
var reminderDate = new Date(row[6]).toLocaleDateString();

    if (reminderDate != today)      // Skip this reminder if not for today
      continue;

    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates

      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message,{name:'Sam'});
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 11).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line of code you're just getting the value of one cell

```
var dataRange= sheet.getRange(startRow,numRows)
```

[getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)

You should change it to:

```
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn())
```

[getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

This way you will only iterate through the values that are in your sheet and you will not work through empty data. If you have several sheets in your spreadsheet try consider to work with the one you have the data, accesing to the right one like this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('NAME OF YOUR SHEET');
```

[getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)